# Is there a standard schema aware binary serialization protocol for JSON?

Tags: json, serialization, binary, protocols, jsonschema

I need to transfer over HTTPS some JSON messages between two endpoint.

I would like to reduce the amount of data transfer between two endpoint at the application layer. I already compressed underlying layers.

The two endpoint will have a pre-shared JSON schema.

Is there a standard schema aware binary serialization protocol for JSON  ?

I'm looking for some sort of JSON binary serialization like http://msgpack.org/ that exploit also the fact that between the two endpoint there are a pre-shared schema.

Comment: I don't want to use a pure binary format due to the loss of flexibility handling the data.

Comment: If you're looking for JSON-like compact serialisation, then you might look at [CBOR](http://cbor.io/) over something like msgpack.

Comment: @cloudfeet does CBOR support json-schema as requested on the question, furthermore I need JSON not JSON-like ?

Comment: No - hence I didn't post it as an answer.  :)  Just responding to msgpack reference.

Comment: ack - anyway thank you for the hints.

Comment: You could measure how much space that such a compression could possibly save by removing all object keys from your JSON (replace:  `/"([^"]|\\.)*"\s*\:/g` with `"_":`).  Do you also have measurements for your bandwidth requirements?  Unless most of this data is going over mobile networks, this optimisation might not be necessary.

Comment: No, JSON struct flexibility should be preserved, furthermore I'm looking for a standard not a custom implementation otherwise I would use a custom binary format. :)

Comment: Sorry - again, I wasn't trying to suggest removing the keys as a solution.  I was actually asking "how much do you *need* to do this", and removing the keys gives you an estimate of possible benefits (assuming such a schema-aware serialisation existed).

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing for a while, but no luck so far!